# What is Skill in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

By looking at my stats on Battlelog, I noticed one labeled "Skill". If I recall, it was also present in Bad Company 2.

What is that statistic? How is it calculated? Mine is 367, is that good?

Comment: BTW. I have doubts how useful this metric is. My favorite class is engineer, which meant that high score, not so high kills. My W/L was high, my score/min also, but "skill" low. Now I'm playing recon, my W/L is low, score/min way down, but "skill" and K/D way up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an [ELO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)-like calculation that can be used to try to make matches with opponents of roughly the same skill level.  I wouldn't worry about whether it's "good" or "bad," but track changes in my own score over a period of time.  A good goal is to consistently improve your score

The [BF3 forums](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654624731770357/) have a rough explanation of how it's calculated:

> So basically, this is what determines your skill level on your stats
>   page:
>
> - You gain/loose[sic] SL based on every confrontation with another player
> - Killing a highly skilled enemy gives you more points than killing someone less skilled
> - Points are not transferred from a player to another, they are simply added/subtracted based on the encounter and the SL of both parts
>     (thus, after an encounter, one part may go up 50 points while the
>     other loses only 20)
> - The SL is used for matchmaking

Comment: this definitely penalizes those players who rank up fast (spend more time playing, etc), since they're going to be encountering lower level people almost all the time by definition... but over time it should settle down as those who play, all rank up to "near" the same levels.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: if it's indeed just ELO, then BF level doesn't matter, it's only SL that matters.

Answer (score 4):

Directly from Dice:

"So basically, this is what determines your skill level on your stats page:

• You gain/lose SL based on every confrontation with another player
• Killing a highly skilled enemy gives you more points than killing someone less skilled
• Points are not transferred from a player to another, they are simply added/subtracted based on the encounter and the SL of both parts (thus, after an encounter, one part may go up 50 points while the other loses only 20)
• The SL is used for matchmaking "

It does not say what skill is high or what is low. Each match your skill is calculated then on battlelog you get your total skill over the course of every game you have played.